# How to Reinitialize a DefaultConsumer's Channel on Shutdown

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using a RabbitMQ DefaultConsumer

```
public void init () {

  DefaultConsumer dc = new DefaultConsumer(channel);

  dc.addShutdownListener(this);

}

handleShutdownSignal() {
   //TODO: Recreate channel associated with this consumer
}
```

Once there is an error with the channel, and a shutdownsignal is sent, how can I reinitialize the channel since the consumer is already dependent on the previous channel it was using ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re establish the connection, create a channel and then create a new consumer.  If the connection is still ok you may be able to use that to get a new channel.